Loop through a list to find three previous elements
Im trying to loop through a list and when I find a certain string, then I want to pull the three previous elements.
Heres a simple example:
my_list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'five']

new = []
for i in my_list:
    if i == 'five':
        context = (my_list[my_list.index(i)-3], my_list[my_list.index(i)-2], my_list[my_list.index(i)-1])
        print(context)


This current code would output:
('two', 'three', 'four')
('two', 'three', 'four')

This is where my problem is! There are two "five" strings, so how do I make this work so that it loops through and prints the previous three elements to every "five"? Ideally, I want it to print this:
('two', 'three', 'four')
('four', 'five', 'six')

How do I get it to match on whatever the current "five" is, instead of just the first one?

After applying the information in the duplicate, note that a slice like my_list[ind-3:ind] (where ind is the index of “five”) is a more compact way to get the previous elements.

You can simply use range(3, len(my_list)):

def get_three_prev(my_list, word):
    new = []
    for i in range(3, len(my_list)):
        if my_list[i] == word:
            context = (my_list[i - 3], my_list[i - 2], my_list[i - 1])
            new.append(context)

    return new


print(get_three_prev(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'five'], 'five'))


Prints
[('two', 'three', 'four'), ('four', 'five', 'six')]


Iterate over the list indexes instead of the list values.
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if my_list[i] == "five":
        print(my_list[i-3], my_list[i-2], my_list[i-1])

You can also use enumerate() to iterate over the index and value at the same time:
for index, value in enumerate(my_list):
    if value == "five":
        ...

